# Why doesn't allow "lang" as function name?

Tags: javascript

I had getting error `Uncaught TypeError: lang is not a function` in calling function name as **lang**. Is `lang` something javascript system name ? It is working after I change function name something like `lan` !! Why was that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lang(v){
          alert(v.value);
            //window.location = "?lang="+v.value;
    }
</script>  
<select onchange="lang(this);">
    <option>En</option>
    <option>Uk</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Because elements have a `lang` IDL attribute which shadows your function.

Comment: You might try `... onchange="window.lang(this)" ...`.